# Clojure: Idiomatic way of merge map's keys based on keys' similarity?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to merge a map's keys based the key value's similarity to produce a new map with the key values similar merged into one. The following is my code to illustrate my ideas:

Given a dataset:

```
(def engineer-visits (incanter.core/dataset ["Engineer" "Credit" "Comments"]
                              [
                               ["Jonah" 1 "OK"]
                               ["Jonah" 2 "Very good"]
                               ["Joneh" 0 "Not very good"]
                               ["Joneh" 3 "Excellent"]
                               ["Esther" 2 "Missing comment"]
                               ["Esther" 4 "Extraordinary"]

                               ]
                              ))
```

with value:

```
| Engineer | Credit |        Comments |
|----------+--------+-----------------|
|    Jonah |      1 |              OK |
|    Jonah |      2 |       Very good |
|    Joneh |      0 |   Not very good |
|    Joneh |      3 |       Excellent |
|   Esther |      2 | Missing comment |
|   Esther |      4 |   Extraordinary |
```

The following produces a map from engineer to his/her records:

```
(def by-engineers (incanter.core/$group-by "Engineer" engineer-visits ))
```

with value:

```
{{"Engineer" "Jonah"} 
| Engineer | Credit |  Comments |
|----------+--------+-----------|
|    Jonah |      1 |        OK |
|    Jonah |      2 | Very good |
, {"Engineer" "Joneh"} 
| Engineer | Credit |      Comments |
|----------+--------+---------------|
|    Joneh |      0 | Not very good |
|    Joneh |      3 |     Excellent |
, {"Engineer" "Esther"} 
| Engineer | Credit |        Comments |
|----------+--------+-----------------|
|   Esther |      2 | Missing comment |
|   Esther |      4 |   Extraordinary |
}
```

With the following function, I'd like to get:

```
(map-merged-by-key-value-similarity by-engineers 0.8)

{{"Engineer" "Jonah"} 
| Engineer | Credit |      Comments |
|----------+--------+---------------|
|    Jonah |      1 |            OK |
|    Jonah |      2 |     Very good |
|    Joneh |      0 | Not very good |
|    Joneh |      3 |     Excellent |
, {"Engineer" "Esther"} 
| Engineer | Credit |        Comments |
|----------+--------+-----------------|
|   Esther |      2 | Missing comment |
|   Esther |      4 |   Extraordinary |
}


(defn map-merged-by-key-value-similarity
      "From a map produced by $gorup-by on a datasest, produce a map of the same structure, with key column values merged by similarity."
      [a-map threshold]
      (let [
            column-keys (keys a-map)
            key-column-name (->> column-keys
                                 first
                                 keys
                                 first)
            ;; Deconstruct the key column values from the key of the map, i.e. the pair of column name and column value:
            key-column-values (flatten (map vals column-keys)) 
            ;; Compute string clusters for the values:
            value-simularity-cluster (similarity-cluster key-column-values threshold)
            ;; Reconstruct the key for the updated map from the clustered column values:
            reconstructed-column-value-key-cluster-list (map (fn [cluster] 
                                                               (map (fn [name] 
                                                                      {key-column-name name})
                                                                    cluster)) 
                                                             value-simularity-cluster)
            representative (fn [cluster] (first cluster)) ; out of a cluster
            map-from-cluster-combined-fn (fn [cluster] 
                                           ; the cluster is a list of maps from key-column-mane to string of the column's value
                                           (if (< 1 (count cluster))
                                             ;; combine
                                             (apply merge-with conj-rows (map (fn [key] 
                                                                                     {(representative cluster) (a-map key)}) 
                                                                                   cluster))
                                             ;; as is
                                             {(first cluster) (a-map (first cluster))}
                                             ))
            ]
        (apply merge (map map-from-cluster-combined-fn reconstructed-column-value-key-cluster-list))
        )
      )
```

The above function indeed works as expected. I'd wish a more idiomatic way to achieve it. As there is a quite symmetry process of decomposing a map's key and value, processing on keys, and reconstructing back a similar map, I feel that it could be more eloquently done. I vaguely remember in Scala, some Mondard operator might be useful to access and process the information buried deep in a list structure.

Thanks for your comment or help!

Note: `similarity-cluster` converts a list of string into a list of list of strings, where similar strings are put into an enclosed list. It's my implementation. The details are not relevant to my question here.

Comment: Please try to present a more isolated case illustrating your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are slightly easier when you just use a table (vector of maps with identical keys) instead of Incanter datasets. However, there are several incanter functions to switch between them.

Also, although you might think your `similarity-cluster` implementation isn't relevant, posting at least something that works similarly will make it a *lot* easier for people to answer your question with working code.

For [measuring similarity between strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) I used this [Purely Functional Levenshtein Distance](https://gist.github.com/ck/960716) as the `levenshtein-distance` function, and used a cutoff point of 3 edits:

```
(def engineer-visits
  [{:comments "OK", :engineer "Jonah", :credit 1}
   {:comments "Very good", :engineer "Jonah", :credit 2}
   {:comments "Not very good", :engineer "Joneh", :credit 0}
   {:comments "Excellent", :engineer "Joneh", :credit 3}
   {:comments "Missing comment", :engineer "Esther", :credit 2}
   {:comments "Extraordinary", :engineer "Esther", :credit 4}])

(defn similarity-matrix
  [coll]
  (into {} (for [x coll, y coll
                 :when (< (levenshtein-distance x y) 3)]
             [x y])))

(def similarity
  (similarity-matrix (distinct (map :engineer engineer-visits))))
=> {"Jonah" "Joneh", "Joneh" "Joneh", "Esther" "Esther"}    

(group-by #(get similarity (:engineer %)) engineer-visits)
=>
{"Joneh"
 [{:comments "OK", :engineer "Jonah", :credit 1}
  {:comments "Very good", :engineer "Jonah", :credit 2}
  {:comments "Not very good", :engineer "Joneh", :credit 0}
  {:comments "Excellent", :engineer "Joneh", :credit 3}],
 "Esther"
 [{:comments "Missing comment", :engineer "Esther", :credit 2}
  {:comments "Extraordinary", :engineer "Esther", :credit 4}]}
```

Of note is that by putting the elements of the similarity-matrix into a hash-map, The `["Jonah","Jonah"]` key-value pair gets overwritten by the following `["Jonah","Joneh"]` pair. The same goes for `["Joneh","Jonah"]` followed by `["Joneh","Joneh"]`. This is pretty instrumental for the result.

Comment: Thanks Niels! The revelation to me is that using the right data structure solves the problem by itself. Incanter is not, but a list of map is in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Niels' answer to make my problem clearer, here should be my problem factoring out non-relevant part:

Given a table, and a way of clustering the column ":engineer"'s values, and a way to select a representative value from a cluster, what's the expression to construct a map from those representatives to the corresponding rows in the table?

Here is the distilled solution. Again thanks to Niels' answer.

```
(def engineer-visits
  [{:comments "OK", :engineer "Jonah", :credit 1}
   {:comments "Very good", :engineer "Jonah", :credit 2}
   {:comments "Not very good", :engineer "Joneh", :credit 0}
   {:comments "Excellent", :engineer "Joneh", :credit 3}
   {:comments "Missing comment", :engineer "Esther", :credit 2}
   {:comments "Extraordinary", :engineer "Esther", :credit 4}])

(defn clusters [names] '(("Jonah" "Joneh") ("Esther")))
(defn representative [cluster] (first cluster))

(def representatives 
  (->> engineer-visits
       (map :engineer)
       distinct
       clusters
       (map (fn [cluster] (apply merge (map (fn [name] {name (representative cluster)}) cluster))))
       (apply merge)
       ))

(group-by #(get representatives (:engineer %)) engineer-visits)
```

Result =>

```
{"Jonah" 
 [{:comments "OK", :engineer "Jonah", :credit 1} 
  {:comments "Very good", :engineer "Jonah", :credit 2} 
  {:comments "Not very good", :engineer "Joneh", :credit 0} 
  {:comments "Excellent", :engineer "Joneh", :credit 3}], 
 "Esther" 
 [{:comments "Missing comment", :engineer "Esther", :credit 2} 
  {:comments "Extraordinary", :engineer "Esther", :credit 4}]}
```